# How to keep the active people from overriding the minority questions?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many times where a group of people will begin an project/activity and then the most vocal members of the group will override the opinions of others.  This causes others to lose faith in the project/activity and wonder off to find something else.  When it comes to questions of faith, I think it's a fire keg ready to blow.

Is there any way to help guide our more active participants towards answers that are non-offensive towards the minority (thereby driving them away)?

Comment: what are you getting at? I'm trying to figure out what issue you see that you are trying to address?

Comment: Simply put, I'm worried that a minority opinion/belief will get downvoted or ridiculed because of the majority's opinion--thereby causing this site to be a place not for "Christianity", but rather "a type of Christianity that the majority or active participants accept".  Having said that, I think the fact that the asker accepts the answer (and not the majority accepts the answer) is probably the very check to keep things in balance.

Comment: Remember that a downvote costs both the voter and the votee and also that one upvote counteracts 5 downvotes in the rep scoring. I wouldn't worry much about it. Yes you will get some downvotes, hopefully we can all coexist, maybe we will even learn something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that we have such a diverse population, I believe that the system already in place of up/down votes will naturally promote the more balanced answers. Especially once this site gets much larger. There's a very relevant article on TVTropes that I'm trying to find right now...

Comment: Did you find that article?

Comment: @TRiG: I never did manage to find the article, but it was about how in a large group, the majority will work to counteract the extremes. For example, if someone goes to a page on Wikipedia and vandalizes it, the edit is reverted very quickly. Or if a page has opinions that are obviously leaning one way, either the page will be edited to a more neutral viewpoint or a notice pointing out the bias will be added.